# The request to read the OneDrive folder information failed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

I'm calling following method in objective c for getting list files and folder of root using onedrive sdk.

```
NSString *folderId = @"me/skydrive/";
[self.liveClient getWithPath:folderId
                    delegate:self
                   userState:@"get folder"];
```

Getting error :The request to read the OneDrive folder information failed.

Am I giving wrong folder id for root?

Answer (score 1):

@"me/skydrive/" is the correct folder-id, it works fine for me. My guess is that you probably haven't set valid permissions for the liveClient object. Make sure you have included either @"wl.skydrive"(for read-only access) or @"wl.skydrive_update"(for read-write access) in the permission-scopes parameter of the liveClient init method.